# Luis Dispatch Model returning inconsistent intent scores

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have multiple LUIS Language Models within a Dispatch Model.  This was published over 7 days ago.

When performing a query via the API I find that:

#### V3 of the API is consistent

Doesn't matter how frequently I call the V3 endpoint with a specific query, I always get the same list of Intents (as in, in the same sequence of confidence), and each Intent's score remains consistent.

#### V2 of the API is not consistent

I call the V2 endpoint with the same query as for the V3 query and it returns the list of Intents and their scores, but these are very different to those returned by V3.  So, my top intent in V3 which had a score of 0.8977665 now comes in 3rd with a score of 0.00916386.

And occasionally, the results flip to be identical to the V3 results, but maybe only for a single query.  It's similar in many ways to hitting a web farm where one of the web servers has the wrong code.

I'm sure both the V2 and V3 APIs must be hitting the same instance of the language models, but I'm not clear on why the V2 would behave in this manner.

It would be interesting to know if anyone else had experienced this with the V2 endpoint and, if so, what was the solution.  It would be even more interesting to know if anyone had experienced this with the V3 endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS responses are [non-deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-prediction-score#differences-with-predictions-between-different-training-sessions) which is to say that there is no guarantee you will always get the same response. This setting can be disabled, as described in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/how-to/train-test#change-deterministic-training-settings-using-the-version-settings-api), by passing in certain values in the LUIS request body via the 'Update application version settings' API:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "UseAllTrainingData",
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "name": "NormalizeDiacritics",
        "value": "false"
    },
    {
        "name": "NormalizePunctuation",
        "value": "false"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, the docs do not state whether this is an option for the v3 API. At a minimum, it is available for v2.

In truth, I find it much more interesting that the v3 API is always returning the same intents in the same order than the v2 API not doing so. Perhaps the v2 API is more sensitive to your scoring thresholds than the v3 API is.